# Importing Customer List fails to show

Tags: customer, email, import, customer-account

I controlled to efficaciously add the patron list within the Magento 2 backend the use of Data Transfer-Import. However, after the system reindexed, the list did not appear in the customers phase.

The list's header consists of the subsequent fields: **Email, _website, confirmation, created_at, created_in, disable_auto_group_change, dob, firstname, gender, organization, lastname, middlename, password_hash, prefix, rp_token, rp_token_created_at, suffix, taxvat, updated_at, website_id, password**.

While a few fields had been left clean, others had been filled in. I was able to import the brand new documents with those headers, however to this point, none of the customers or their emails are showing.